# Why are links to social media and GitHub not appearing in the SE data dump?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, profile-page, hyperlinks, data-dump

I am looking in the Users table for Stack Overflow in the [SE data dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) and have noticed something strange. There is a field for the website, namely `WebsiteUrl`.

However, if a user has filled this in and in addition also posted a link to his a GitHub, Twitter, LinkedIn, etc. profile, then we only see the website and not the links to these social media profiles. Why is that? Is there perhaps a way to retrieve also the social media / GitHub links?

As an example, consider the famous [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet). In his profile, he includes links to his website, GitHub and Twitter accounts. However, in the Users table we can only see his website, namely `'http://csharpindepth.com'`, in the `WebsiteUrl` field.

Comment: The [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids#order=desc&sort=reputation&ids=22656&site=stackoverflow&run=true) doesn't have these fields either.

Comment: @rene and neither does SEDE.... looks like SE never exposed those outside for some reason.

Comment: Maybe they this is because they are inside of the about-me text?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those don't appear in the data dump or in SEDE because the social media/GitHub links aren't stored in the `Users` table - it only has the `WebsiteUrl` column.

The others links are stored in a separate `UsersMetadata` table that isn't included in any of the public data dumps.